# Bad:Converting pdf to images

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

Convert class:

```
  public void getImage(String pdfFilename) throws Exception{

        List<byte[]> listImg = new ArrayList<>();
        try (final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilename))){
            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
            {
                File file = new File("C:\\path1\\"+page+".png");

                BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImage(page);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(bim, "png",file);


                System.out.println("!!!!");
              //  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listImg.get(page)));



            }
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Exception while trying to create pdf document - " + e);
        }

    }
```

**Everything works well**. All pdf files are converted, but **if** I use the class shw (this is very necessary for my project):

```
 PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(DEST1));
        Rectangle rect = srcDoc.getFirstPage().getPageSize();
        System.out.println(rect);
        Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(pageSize));
        System.out.println(srcDoc.getNumberOfPages());
        PdfCanvas content = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());

        int n = 0;
        for (int i =1 ; i <= srcDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {

            PdfFormXObject page = srcDoc.getPage(i).copyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
            content.clip();
            content.newPath();


               content.addXObject(page,MainPdf.right_Margin-MainPdf.left_Margin,0);
           content = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());

                for (double y = 4.251969f; y <= 595; y += 14.1732) {
                    content.moveTo(0, y);
                    content.lineTo(420, y);
                }
                for (double x = 0; x <= 420; x += 14.1732) {
                    content.moveTo(x, 0);
                    content.lineTo(x, 595);
                }
                content.closePathStroke();


        }

        srcDoc.close();
        pdfDoc.close();
    }
```

Those images that have been converted to empty (contain nothing inside themselves, just a white background). Pdf not empty.
pdf:https://dropmefiles.com/UXedd

[image: [enter image description here]
images:

> [image]

Comment: Is the problem that generated PDF files are empty or that you render pdf to image and image is empty?

Comment: Please share the pdf before and after the itext class and mention what versions of itext and pdfbox you are using.

Comment: Doesn't "content" (PdfCanvas) have to be closed in some way? Does release() have to be called or does itext keep records of open content streams?

Comment: PDF not empry, empty Images

Comment: I hadn't seen that you had edited the question. I see it now and had a look at the file. Likely a PDFBox effect, related to content.clip(); in the main content stream. This sets a empty (?!) clipping path. Adobe ignores it, but PDFBox doesn't. Please try removing that call. If you tried this, then don't forget to respond as a comment and add "@Tilman Hausherr" so I get notified. I have also tried other viewers: PDF.js and GhostScript don't display it, Chrome and Edge display it.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr   thank you very much!!!!!! Everything is working!!

Comment: As an aside, the code for creating a grid (the `for` loops over `double` variables) also miss a drawing instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause was the call

```
content.clip();
```

in the itext segment. This clips with an empty path. Adobe Reader ignores this, but PDFBox doesn't, so the current clipping path is empty so that nothing gets seen.

Per one of the comments, removing that call solves the problem. (I suspect that `content.newPath();` isn't needed either)

I have also tried other viewers: PDF.js and GhostScript don't display it, Chrome and Edge display it.

Comment: To put it a bit more clearly: `clip` and `newPath` without a preceding path *create invalid content streams.* Thus, neither of the tested viewers is less or more correct.